# Linq to Excel - Object must implement IConvertible error

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-excel

The following code is showing this error

> Object must implement IConvertible

when I am adding the where clause in the LINQ expression to compare the `DateTime` field.

I tried to use `Convert.ToDateTime(c.ETC) >= startday` but still the same error.

```
var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory(excelfilename);
excel.AddMapping<BulkMovementItem>(x => x.ETC, "ETC");

var newrailtruckmovements = (from c in excel.Worksheet<BulkMovementItem>(sheetname)                  
    where c.ETC > new DateTime(2015, 7, 1) 
    select c);
```

Definition of `BulkMovementItem`:

```
public class BulkMovementItem
{
    public string  ScheduleName { get; set; }   
    public string  DealHeaderName { get; set; } 
    public string DealDetailName { get; set; }
    public string ETC { get; set; }
    public string RailcarName { get; set; } 
    public string Location   { get; set; }
    public string OriginLocation { get; set; }  
    public string FunctionType { get; set; } 
    public string ProductName { get; set; } 
    public string Volume { get; set; }  
    public string SupplierUniqueNbr { get; set; }

    // Error Description
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public bool HasErrors { get; set; }
    //public List<string> ErrorDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `ETC`?

Comment: Posting the definition of `BulkMovementItem` would help.

Comment: And I assume this is the [LinqToExcel](https://github.com/paulyoder/LinqToExcel) library? It would be helpful if you include that in your question.

Comment: I'm going to guess that `ETC` is a string? In that case, you are going to need to [parse it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: ETC is a string field.

Comment: I can fix this by adding Tolist() as below before where clause. but I don't want to do that way as I am reading the whole list before filtering. My objective here to improve the performance of this query   var newrailtruckmovements = (from c in excel.Worksheet<BulkMovementItem>(sheetname).ToList()
                                                             where Convert.ToDateTime(c.ETC) >= StartDate && Convert.ToDateTime(c.ETC) < EndDate
                                                             select c);

Comment: @Matt Burland - I parsed it as below but no luck.    excel.AddMapping<BulkMovementItem>(x => x.ETC, "ETC", s => String.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? DateTime.MinValue :
                                                  DateTime.ParseExact(s, @"MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat));

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change `ETC`'s type in your class to `DataTime`. The library will do the rest:

```
public class BulkMovementItem {
    // some fields...
    public DateTime ETC { get; set; }
    // rest of fields...
}
```

And this would work:

```
var rows = from c in excel.Worksheet<BulkMovementItem>(sheetname)                  
           where c.ETC > new DateTime(2015, 7, 1) 
           select c;
```